# How to interlace two integers in C?

Tags: c, math

Let say I have two ints

`a = 1234`
`b = 45678`

Now I want to "interlace" them into a third int `c` that looks something like this
`c = 415263748` assume the the length of these don't change. So far I've been able to do this:

```c
unsigned interlace(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    unsigned pow = 10;
    while(y >= pow)
        pow *= 10;
    return x * pow + y;        
}
```

Comment: The last decimal digit of (positive) integer `b` is `b % 10`. To "interlace" it with the last digit of `a` you can do `10 * (a % 10) + (b % 10)`. Then divide by `10` to shift the numbers right by one digit and repeat.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get digits one by one. When you say `x % 10` you get the least significant digit. When you say `x = x /10` you remove the least significant digit. Start doing it for y then keep alternating:

```
unsigned interlace(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
   //If the parameters order could be inverted...
   if(x > y)
   {
      unsigned z = x;
      x = y;
      y = z;
   }
   unsigned ans = y % 10;
   y = y/10;
   unsigned exponent = 10;
   while(y)
   {
       ans += (x%10)*exponent;
       x = x/10;
       exponent *= 10;
       ans += (y%10)*exponent;
       y = y/10;
       exponent *= 10;
   }
   return ans;
}
```

Comment: Fails if the order of parameters are reversed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `assume the the length of these don't change`. I've assumed. Did you?

Comment: Nope, I figured that the user could do something screwy so I just checked the lengths to find out which one is longer. Changing the parameter order does not change the lengths. Note: I did not downvote, because you can presume the user will pass the values in the order shown. But you can also protect against the user doing something dumb as well `:)`

Comment: Well, still it is much cheaper to add an if then use strings... and by the code she provided, she seemed to want to solve it by math only

Comment: No worries, it works fine for the problem shown. I like it.

Comment: `int exponent = 10;` --> `unsigned exponent = 10;` to avoid potential UB due to `int` overflow - no need to introduce another type.

Answer (score 1):

A slight twist on approach can eliminate the order of parameter issue by handling the interlacing on string representations of the values. This allows a simple way to sew the two numbers together. While `strlen()` is used here, you can also use `snprintf (NULL, 0, "%u", a)` and `snprintf (NULL, 0, "%u", b)` to determine the number of digits in each.

A simple approach interlacing the string representations would be:

```
#define NUMC 32

unsigned interlace (unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    char sa[NUMC], sb[NUMC], result[2*NUMC];
    size_t lena, lenb, n = 0;
    
    sprintf (sa, "%u", a);
    sprintf (sb, "%u", b);
    
    lena = strlen(sa);
    lenb = strlen(sb);
    
    if (lena > lenb) {
        for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; sa[i]; i++) {
            result[n++] = sa[i];
            if (sb[j])
                result[n++] = sb[j++];
        }
        result[n] = 0;
        
        return (unsigned)strtoul (result, NULL, 0);
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; sb[i]; i++) {
        result[n++] = sb[i];
        if (sa[j])
            result[n++] = sa[j++];
    }
    result[n] = 0;
    
    return (unsigned)strtoul (result, NULL, 0);
}
```

(**note:** the validations on conversion and length checks greater than zero should be added above. They were intentionally omitted for brevity)

The order of parameters is irrelevant. You can call it as `interlace (a, b)` or `interlace (b, a)` and the result will be correct each time.

A short example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUMC 32

unsigned interlace (unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    char sa[NUMC], sb[NUMC], result[2*NUMC];
    size_t lena, lenb, n = 0;
    
    sprintf (sa, "%u", a);
    sprintf (sb, "%u", b);
    
    lena = strlen(sa);
    lenb = strlen(sb);
    
    if (lena > lenb) {
        for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; sa[i]; i++) {
            result[n++] = sa[i];
            if (sb[j])
                result[n++] = sb[j++];
        }
        result[n] = 0;
        
        return (unsigned)strtoul (result, NULL, 0);
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; sb[i]; i++) {
        result[n++] = sb[i];
        if (sa[j])
            result[n++] = sa[j++];
    }
    result[n] = 0;
    
    return (unsigned)strtoul (result, NULL, 0);
}

int main (void) {
    
    unsigned a = 1234, b = 45678;
    
    printf ("interlaced: %u\n", interlace (a, b));
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/interlace_int
interlaced: 415263748
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you asked for but maybe you can reuse some of this logic on your function....

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
Interlace 2 numbers as a printf
Enter number a: forty-three
Insert digit  : 1234
Enter number b: 45678
Interlaced numbers: 142536478
```

---

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    long int num , num2, temp , factor = 1, factor2 = 1;

    puts("Interlace 2 numbers as a printf");

    printf("Enter number a: ");
    while(!scanf(" %ld",&num)){
        while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n' && temp != EOF);
        printf("Insert digit  : ");
    }

    printf("Enter number b: ");
    while(!scanf(" %ld",&num2)){
        while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n' && temp != EOF);
        printf("Insert digit  : ");
    }

    temp = num;
    while(temp){
      temp   /= 10;
      factor *= 10;
    }

    temp = num2;
    while(temp){
      temp    /= 10;
      factor2 *= 10;
    }       

    printf("Interlaced numbers: ");
    while(factor>1)
    {
        factor /= 10;
        printf("%ld",num/factor);
        num %= factor;
        if (factor2 > 1)
        {
            factor2 /= 10;
            printf("%ld",num2/factor2);
            num2 %= factor2;
        }
    }

    while(factor2>1)
    {
        factor2 /= 10;
        printf("%ld",num2/factor2);
        num2 %= factor2;
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like where you are going with it, but what happens if you enter `45678` and `1234` like in the question?  (aside: since `[Enter]` is pressed following `scanf(" %d",&num2);` nothing remains in `stdout` to `fflush(stdout);`. Also `puts ("");` is actually `putchar ('\n');` no need to scan for `'\0'` when outputting 1-char) What happens when you ask `"Enter number a: "` and the user types `"forty-three"`? How is that error detected and handled? (just curious) And, what of the rule *"You can't use any input function correctly unless you* ***check the return*** *?"*

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i make some changes on my code acording your "recomendations", scanf it's more user safe now and the lenght of input numbers don't matter anymore

Comment: Much better, entering `45678` and `1234` results in the wanted answer (but the reverse doesn't) The scheme works if you always start with the longest number first. Checking with `snprintf (NULL, 0, "%ld", num1)` will tell you how many digits are needed (hence the length). You can then determine which number to start with first. `while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n' && temp != EOF);` is only needed if the next input does not discard leading whitespace. All `scanf()` conversion specifiers EXCEPT `"%c"`, `"%[..]"` and `"%n"` discard leading whitespace. All said, much improved, ++1.

Comment: True that, actually i wrongly assumed first input is the base for the interlace result, btw thanks for the tips i'll have that in consideration on my future implementations

Answer (score 1):

Another completely different approach, more inline with your original can make use of the `div` function and the `div_t` struct to automate handling the division and remainder. You can use the `snprintf (NULL, 0, "%u", var);` function to determine the number of digits so you can swap parameters if necessary.

A short example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned interlace (unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    unsigned result = 0, mult = 1;
    div_t da = { .quot = a }, db = { .quot = b };
    
    if (snprintf (NULL, 0, "%u", b) > snprintf (NULL, 0, "%u", a)) {
        div_t tmp = da;
        da = db;
        db = tmp;
    }
    
    do {
        da = div (da.quot, 10);
        result += da.rem * mult;
        mult *= 10;
        
        if (db.quot) {
            db = div (db.quot, 10);
            result += db.rem * mult;
            mult *= 10;
        }
    } while (da.quot);
    
    return result;
}

int main (void) {
    
    unsigned a = 1234, b = 45678;
    
    printf ("interlaced: %u\n", interlace (a, b));
}
```

(**note:** here again, the order of parameters is irrelevant and you can provide `a` and `b` in any order and still arrive at the correct result)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/interlace_unsinged
interlaced: 415263748
```

Let me know if you have further questions. Just another way to skin the interlace cat.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
    int a = 1234;
    int b = 45678;
    int c = 0;
    
    while(a || b)
    {
        if (b)
        {
            int m = pow(10, (int)log10(b)); 
            c=c*10 + b/m;
            b = b%m;
        }
        if (a)
        {
            int m = pow(10, (int)log10(a)); 
            c=c*10+a/m;
            a = a%m;
        }
    }
    printf("Result: %d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4692KB
Result: 415263748
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/NqLaLw)

Comment: Is there another way to do it? I dont wanna use math.h library

Comment: @lolnoname I've posted one. If you care about the order of the parameters you should just add a check to swap them if x is greater than y

Answer (score 0):

> Appending the last digit of the two numbers alternatively to n * 10(repeated operation), gives you the reverse of the interlace.
> Just to help if you are stuck in generating reversed interlace.

```
unsigned interlace (unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
    unsigned n, r;
    if( x > y)
    {
        temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }

    n = y % 10;
    y = y / 10;
    
    while (x || y) // To Generate reverse of the interlace
    {
        n = n * 10 + (x % 10);
        x /= 10;
          
        n = n * 10 + (y % 10);
        y /= 10;
    }
  
    r = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    while(n != 0) // reverse it to get the interlaced number
    {
        r = r * 10 + (n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }

    return r;

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just added the code to Generate the reverse of the interlace.